# How to change time limit in phpmyadmin (logging in)

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use phpmyadmin to create mysql database. And I have set the auth type to cookie in the config.inc.php.
How do I change the time limit so that even if I logged in I stayed idle for hours it won't require me to log in again.

Comment: Should be asked in http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for this:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '3600');
```

As per the comments -  You can find it in php.ini file or run the above statement in your script where you are setting session

Comment: can you specify where can it be found?

Comment: @user225269: You can find it in `php.ini` file or run the above statement in your script where you are setting session.

Comment: @Sarfraz So I can set it somewhere in main phpmyadmin file so when it loads it would use those settings?

Answer (score 43):

I know this question is getting old, but the above 'selected' answer doesn't actually work. That just sets the time til session data gets removed.

After trying this and realizing it was failing, I spent some time reading through the phpmyadmin docs and found this:

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;
$cfg['LoginCookieStore'] = 0;
```

The first line is the amount of time until you're auto-logged out. These values need to be set in your phpmyadmin install folder, within the file `config.inc.php`.

They were not there at all in my file but after adding them to the bottom it worked correctly. The first variable defines how long until you are logged out in seconds - I set mine to 1 day. The second variable is how long the cookie lasts. 0 means the cookie lasts til you close your browser.

Setting up these two variables will have the desired effect. You could set both to some insane number and never log in, but that would be pretty insecure.

Comment: Very strange that the new versions of phpMyAdmin has removed this setting from Settings -> Features tab.

Answer (score 10):

**Fast solution for Ubuntu:**

---

// edit `php.ini` and look for `session.gc_maxlifetime`
sudo vi /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

// set to 24 hours
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400

---

// edit `config.inc.php` and look for `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']`
sudo vi /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

// set to 24 hours
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 86400;

---

// restart web server
sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 8):

In my case(4.3.8) just replace in `config.inc.php` `cookie` to `config` and add 2 lines like bellow:

```
/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['username'] = 'root'; //add this line
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root'; //add this line
```

Comment: On debian-based systems, this is at `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the tricks, assuming you have at least the version 4.3.X :

First, log to phpMyAdmin, once log in, click on **Databases** *(located at the top menu)*

Then on the input text **Create database**, insert **phpmyadmin** and click on **Create** *(you can select your wished charset, this is optional)*

When the database is created, click to it on the list *(should appear with your other database)*

click to SQL and insert the contents of **create_tables.sql** located to your directory phpMyAdmin :

```
/phpMyAdmin-(yourversion)-all-languages/sql/create_tables.sql
```

*You can optionally dump it in command line (terminal) :*

```
mysql phpmyadmin -u myMysqluser -pMypassword < create_tables.sql
```

Now that's done, open your **config.inc.php** and uncomment those 2 lines :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
```

Note that if you don't uncomment the other **$cfg['Servers'][$i]**, phpmyadmin will return :

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. Or
>   alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

Which is just a warning concerning the other options available. *(if you don't need them, let them comment)*

Logout and login again to phpMyAdmin and go to **Settings** *(located at the top menu between Import and Replication)* and click on **Features** you will see the option :

```
Login cookie validity
```

Where you have to put in seconds, the validity of the cookie.

Click on **Apply** and it's done, the record will be save for this user in the table **pma__userconfig** in the database previously created (phpmyadmin), the record 
will look like this :

```
{"LoginCookieValidity":21600,"Server\/hide_db":"","collation_connection":"utf8mb4_unicode_ci"}
```

If the validity of your cookie (in seconds) is greater than your session_gc_maxlifetime, phpMyAdmin will return a warning :

> Your PHP parameter session.gc_maxlifetime is lower than the cookie
>   validity configured in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login might
>   expire sooner than configured in phpMyAdmin

**session_gc_maxlifetime** is located to your **php.ini**, change it and restart your webserver if the above warning appear.

Comment: That was exactly what i was searching for! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid cookie authentication altogether and use

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`

in your `config.inc.php` file found under the `phpmyadmin` folder.

This will keep you logged in forever.

Comment: missing some steps I think